# Multisig doesn't work unless all keys were generated from the current wallet?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, multi-signature

I tried to create a multisig in both the Bitcoin network and the Bitcoin testnet. It seems to work only when all public keys are from the current wallet. That means when I call `listunspent` after I send coin to the multisig address, it didn't show up as a multisig address unless this multisig address was created from the current wallet. I tried it in both real coin and testnet. What is problem?

Note: I use Bitcoin-qt 0.9.2.1

**Why "listunspent" dosen't show multisig address ?**

**How can i check balance of multisig address and get txid and vout and scriptPubKey for multisig address ?**

**Edit 2:I try to search for software(tool) can be track bitcoin address (balance and transactions) i found bitcoin-abe, but  when i search for it i found i can't search for bitcoin address to retrieve it balance and transaction ? anyone know tool like blockchain when i request about bitcoin address give me balance and transactions ?**

Comment: no answer !!!!!

Comment: Give it a little more time, it was in the middle of the night on half the planet. Alternatively, you can try to give your question more exposure by linking it in social networks or such.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in multisig support in the reference client is only a proof-of-concept. As until recently (and still) the wallet did not deal well with coins being spent outside of its control, it was decided to only allow spending multisig coins when you have all keys. Of course that completely defeats the purpose of multisig, but proper support for it requires separate tools anyway (to pass the partially signed transactions around, etc).

However, the planned watch-only wallet support does allow watching multisig addresses too (in fact, any script at all), which will appear in listunspent. Clearly, the regular `sendtoaddress` & co RPCs cannot spend these coins, but it does give the ability to track them.

Comment: how can i know the balance of multisig address ? is there any api RPC to get balance and transaction of multisig address ?

Comment: if there isn't api RPC to get balance of multisig address and its transactions, is there exist blockchain.info api to get balance of multisig addreess and its transactions ?

Comment: No, to know the balance, you need the wallet to track the transactions. The current wallet implementation in the reference client does not consider a transaction 'ours' when it pays to a multisig address you don't have all keys for. The planned watch-only functionality will allow this, by consider a transactions 'ours' without the ability to spend from it.

Comment: What is means of "The planned watch-only functionality" ?

Comment: Pieter Wuille: i want know know how can i get multisig balance and txid and vout and scriptPubKey to send fund from it ? what is steps ?

Comment: How to do it now? Use software that supports it. The reference client's wallet currently doesn't, but it is far from the only wallet client out there. There is a planned feature that will likely make it into the next major release (watch-only wallets) that will allow you to track transactions crediting arbitrary scripts, which will allow you to do that.

Comment: what is software that supports it ? can you give me example please ? thanks your efforts for answering my question

Comment: Pieter Wuille : can you please answer my question ?

Comment: bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress. you can use this command to get the balance of any address @Dev777

Comment: @Vivek no. It tells you how much *your wallet* received on that address. It does not list a balance, and it does not work for addresses outside your wallet. You can import addresses without corresponding keys now though, through `importaddress`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at APIs that support both multisig address and building multisig transactions as support in Bitcoin Core is still partial. For example:

http://dev.blockcypher.com/#multisig